# How to pass variable arguments/ an object holding variable arguments in java?

Tags: java, argument-passing, variadic-functions

What I'm trying to do is to create an interface that can be used to implement a connection class. I should be able to use this for different authentication like LDAP, OpenId etc; So I want to pass username,password and variable number of arguments. How do I do that.. I tried this. Am I going in the right direction.? If so, how do I initialize the object to hold variable parameters.? Newbie to java. would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks!

```
package com.cerner.jira.plugins.esig.servicemanager;
import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;

public interface AuthenticationServiceManager {

   /**
    * Creates the Connection for the specific user logging in, and binds the
    * user's credentials to  object.
    * 
    * @param userName
    *            The user name to authenticate .
    * @param password
    *            The user's password to check .
    * @param args
    *            is an object that holds variable arguments which can be used
    *            to authenticate using both LDAP and OpenId
    * @return boolean The connection status showing whether the user has been
    *         successfully authenticated or not.
    * @throws AuthenticationException
    *             If there is an error authenticating with the passed
    *             parameters
    **/

    boolean authenticate(String username, String password, Object... args)
        throws AuthenticationException;

    /**
    * Disconnects the connection.
    */
    void disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Are you using java 5 or above ? What exact error do you get ? If there is no error, go ahead. Launch and test as soon as you can.

Comment: I'm using java 6... As I'm new I just wanted to make sure.. and see if there is an alternative or better way to do it

Comment: The machine is your [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor), not SOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got it. You call it like this:

```
authenticate(username, password, someOtherArgument, yetAnotherArgument, stillAnotherArgument);
```

And then inside your method, `args[0]` will contain `someOtherArgument`, `args[1]` will contain `yetAnotherArgument` and `args[2]` will contain `stillAnotherArgument`.

Comment: Well, If I want to just pass username and password in authenticate method of implementing class. Should I make the class abstract??

Comment: You can still call `authenticate(username, password);`, `args` will then be an empty `Object[]`.

Comment: `@Override
 public boolean authenticate(String Username, String password, String url)

 {
  return false;

 }`



WHen i Use this it says The method authenticate(String, String, String) of type AuthenticationManagerImpl must override or implement a supertype method.

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: Well, That was just a method from the class that implements the interface... The whole point was to pass variable parameters. I dont understand why I get the error